# pandas data frame has only one column but actually it has multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I want to do is sort my data by IRI_KEY but I meet some problem
Because when I try

```
Z['IRI_KEY']
KeyError: u'no item named IRI_KEY'
```

It tells me that they don't have IRI_KEY but actually it has

So what I tried is watch there array

My data has no specific type like csv

```
mayo_groc = 'mayo_groc_1322_1373'
Z = pd.read_table(mayo_groc,sep=',', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=True)
Z

       IRI_KEY WEEK SY GE VEND  ITEM  UNITS DOLLARS  F    D PR
  0    234212 1322  0  1 21000 77742    18    54.00 ...     
  1    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64005    11    30.69 ...     
  2    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64012     8    30.32 ...     
  3    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64508    13    38.87 ...     
  4    234212 1322  0  1 21000 77749    14    42.00 ...     
  5    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64004    14    39.06 ...     
  6    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64507    11    32.89 ...     
  7    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64512     6    22.74 ...     
  8    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64591     5    13.45 ...     
  9    234212 1322  0  1 21000 64510    14    41.86 ...
```

[2444224 rows x 1 columns]

Why it has only one columns?
and how can I fix this problem?

Here is sample actual data 
It doesn't have any extension so I read it by vi command

```
vi mayo_groc_1322_1373

IRI_KEY WEEK SY GE VEND  ITEM  UNITS DOLLARS  F    D PR
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 77742    18    54.00 B    0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64005    11    30.69 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64012     8    30.32 NONE 0 1
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64508    13    38.87 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 77749    14    42.00 B    0 1
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64004    14    39.06 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64507    11    32.89 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64512     6    22.74 A    0 1
```

Comment: pls post a sample of the actual csv

Comment: Thanks for asking. It isn't csv file it doesn't have extension

Comment: I will attach samples soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is not "comma separated", but instead "whitespace delimited".  Have you tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file', delim_whitespace=True)
```

as in:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """IRI_KEY WEEK SY GE VEND  ITEM  UNITS DOLLARS  F    D PR
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 77742    18    54.00 B    0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64005    11    30.69 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64012     8    30.32 NONE 0 1
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64508    13    38.87 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 77749    14    42.00 B    0 1
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64004    14    39.06 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64507    11    32.89 NONE 0 0
 234212 1322  0  1 21000 64512     6    22.74 A    0 1"""

filelike = StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(filelike, delim_whitespace=True)
```